# NTFS-3G partition name contains increasing number

Tags: macos, mount, ntfs

When using NTFS-3G using OSXFuse installed via Homebrew, my Windows drives are mounted but contain a number that is increased every time the volume is mounted:

[image]

These numbers don't seem to be limited. I have to regularly delete all the unused mount points. I'm assuming this problem could also occur because of insufficient permissions for some process, but I'm not sure for which or how to verify this.

/Volumes/ has the permissions 777 and owner root:admin.

The annoying effect of the changing mount point is that I cannot make links to a particular path on the Windows drive. At the next restart it will have changed...

Comment: This happens to me on occasion with all types of partition, usually because I didn't unmount the disk before physical disconnection. Are you ejecting the disk?

Comment: I can't, these are internal hard disk partitions in my mac. Hmm, if I think about this a bit more, it could happen when the computer doesn't completely shutdown. I'll try to investigate.

Comment: [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osxfuse-group/zwoEEWrdnug) lists the same problem, and suggests a possible workaround (add it to fstab).

Comment: Ok, it seems that it's [known issue with osxfuse](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/119). The problem didn't appear with fuse4x, so you can downgrade according to the above thread or circumvent Mac's automount, which editing fstab implicitly does.

Answer (score 1):

Using OSXFUSE with version 2.7 on the Mavericks this working.

Since I can not post more than 2 links, read a tutorial I posted and solved my problem in this link!

https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/119

Comment: Whilst this link may answer the question, it is preferable to include the content of the link in the answer and provide the link for reference.